# IBM ODM 8.8 - Error updating dynamic domain in DE (teamserver)

Tags: ibm-odm

I've implemented a dynamic domain that retrieves values from a database. I've repackaged the EAR file and redeployed at WAS successfully. I'm using ODM 8.8.

When I try to reload the domain at teamserver, I'm getting the following error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Error calling action method of component with id paneForm:asynchAction
     at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:72)
     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)
     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastForPhase(UIViewRoot.java:97)
     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:171)
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:95)
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:70)
     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:139)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.security.SecurityCheckPointFilter.doFilter(SecurityCheckPointFilter.java:118)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.servlets.filter.IlrAccessFilter.doFilter(IlrAccessFilter.java:198)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.servlets.filter.IlrRemoteSessionFilter.doFilterInternal(IlrRemoteSessionFilter.java:88)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.servlets.filter.IlrRemoteSessionFilter.doFilter(IlrRemoteSessionFilter.java:66)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.servlets.filter.IlrSessionFilter.access$001(IlrSessionFilter.java:32)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.servlets.filter.IlrSessionFilter$1.doFilter(IlrSessionFilter.java:62)
     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.servlets.filter.IlrSessionFilter.doFilter(IlrSessionFilter.java:60)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.servlets.filter.IlrFileUploadFilter.doFilter(IlrFileUploadFilter.java:45)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
 Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception while invoking expression #{SelectionBean.asynchAction}
     at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:156)
     at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:61)
     ... 51 more
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.transaction.IlrConnectionHolderJTA.closeConnection(IlrConnectionHolderJTA.java:112)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.transaction.IlrConnectionHolderJTA.popTx(IlrConnectionHolderJTA.java:55)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.transaction.IlrTransactionManager.endTransaction(IlrTransactionManager.java:106)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.transaction.IlrTransactionalInvocationHandler.invoke(IlrTransactionalInvocationHandler.java:47)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy308.reloadDynamicDomains(Unknown Source)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.model.impl.IlrAbstractSession.reloadDynamicDomains(IlrAbstractSession.java:1953)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.beans.DynamicDomainsBean.reloadDynamicDomains(DynamicDomainsBean.java:66)
     at ilog.rules.teamserver.web.beans.SelectionBean.asynchAction(SelectionBean.java:521)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
     at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:132)
     ... 52 more
```

The domain works fine at Rule Designer. I also know that my class that implements IlrBOMDomainValueProvider is called because I added some logs. Besides, when I select the option read to be updated and I really have a domain updated, the domain is shown at the list. The error just occurs when I try to update the domain clicking on the Update button.

Does anyone have any idea to help me with this error?